# jQuery pass a input field value to a get method redirect url laravel 5

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, input, routes

I'm working a Order List using Laravel 5 and I have this Reject button which is like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/86LdasLc/4/)

When it is clicked it will confirm if the user really want to reject then if yes it will redirected to a specified route like so

```
Route::get('reject-order/{ordernum}', 'OrderController@rejectCustomerOrder');
```

Then in my `rejectCustomerOrder`

```
public function rejectCustomerOrder($ordernum)
{
   var_dump(Input::get('reject_reason')); exit;
   CustomerOrder::where('order_number', '=', $ordernum)->update(['status' => 2]);
   $data = CustomerOrder::where('order_number', '=', $ordernum)->get();
   $user = User::find($data[0]->created_by_id);

   Mail::send('emails.message-rejected', ['user' => $user->name, 'order_num' => $ordernum], function ($m) use ($user) {
            $m->to($user->email, '')->subject('Custtomer Order Rejected');
});
```

Problem is i can't get the `reject_reason` input field. It's always null. When you click the x button (reject button) it will ask if you really want to reject and you need to put the reject reason on the text field. How can I get that or pass it in the route?

Comment: Well if it's a redirect it's normal that you don't get it, unless you do a POST or a redirect with a GET parameter

Comment: show the url for that controller method.

Comment: @ImtiazPabel the url is in the route i posted above

Comment: first try return Input::all() and then see what input reached in server

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the following parameter in this method.

rejectCustomerOrder($ordernum,Request $request)

the access this way:
$request->reject_reason

Answer (score 0):

Fixed now. :) Was able to so by making it

```
<a class="btn btn-danger btn-ok" id="btnReject">Reject</a>
```

And adding

```
$("#reject_reason").keyup(function() {
    var oldDataHref = $("#btnReject").attr('href');
    var newDataHref = oldDataHref + $('#reject_reason').val();
    $("#btnReject").attr('href', newDataHref);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a "post" route you don't need the parameter in route definition. If it's a "any"  or "get" type then it's ok to have it there.
So, if it's POST then you can get the value with Input::get('input_name') and if it's get you can simply get it trought the controller method parameter, in your case $ordernum.